# Selectivity of olefin cross-metathesis reaction

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis, catalysis, organometallic-compounds

I'm looking at the reaction shown below which uses a ruthenium catalyst:

[image]

I am confused because the ruthenium catalyst which is used in the reaction should be Z selective due to the features on the catalyst because the adamantyl group favours the side bound pathway i.e. the Z isomer and the di-iso-propyl phenyl group blocks the path to the E alkene.

Comment: Did you perform this reaction and get that result? Are you looking at some publication that publishes this?

Comment: Is there an error in the reaction?  The reactant has 5 carbons, and the product has 8.  If this is supposed to be a dimerization, what happens to the two missing carbons?

Comment: @CurtF. There doesn't appear to be a mistake. This is standard olefin metathesis. Ethylene is the assumed by-product.

Comment: I see.  Olefin metathesis is cool.

Comment: @CurtF. They did give out 3 Nobel Prizes for it in 2005...

Comment: @Jan just looking at a publication

Comment: Please add/cite your source then =)